# How to show pipe separated string into different td in dynamic html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this data in array:

```
Pune|M, Mumbai|O
```

and I want to show this data into html table, so for that I did this:

```
var arr;
arr = obj[0][2];

var j=0;
$.each(arr, function(){
    var html = "<tr><td>" + arr[j] + "</td><td><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' onclick='remove_locations1()'></span></td></tr>";
    j = j + 1;
    $('#table_display_locations1').append(html);
});
```

obj[0][2] contain the

> Pune|M, Mumbai|O

I manage to display the data like this:

```
Pune|M 
Mumbai|O
```

but I want to show in first row as Pune and M in two different td's and in second row, Mumbai and O display in two different td's.

I tried split function, but it wont work for me.
can anyone please  tell how I manage my string to display the result which I want?
Help?

Comment: All works fine, I just want to display Pune and M in different <td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var j=0;
$.each(arr, function(){
    var split_array = arr[j].split('|');
    var split_result = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < split_array.length; i++) {
        var split_result = split_result + '<td>'+split_array[i]+'</td>';
    }

    var html = "<tr>" + split_result + "<td><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' onclick='remove_locations1()'></span></td></tr>";
    j = j + 1;
    $('#table_display_locations1').append(html);
});
```

Comment: Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: You'll need to place this code in your `each` loop before you create the html variable, and replace `arr[j]` with `split_result`. I've updated my answer to factor it into your code.

Comment: It add's extra td initially and then remaining output

Comment: Updated the solution. It was just the extra td element you had in the string.

Answer (score 0):

First use foreach in the main array, split each entries using `|`,

Try the below code.

```js
var arr=["Pune|M","Mumbai|O"];
var text="";
arr.forEach(x => { text +="<tr>"; x.split('|').forEach(y => text+="<td>"+y+"<td />"); text +="</tr>";});
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML=text;

console.log(text);
```

```html
<table>

</table>
```